# SQL Query to Unpivot dependent column using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i am trying to replicate below scenario using oracle sql query:

[image]

> 

i have did it using union query , but in that query i am hitting  same table multiple times, is there any alternate for this query?

**Please note:** col and val are depenedent on each other simillarly  col_1 and val_1 are also dependent on each other

```
select id,col, val from tbl
union
select id,col_1, val_1 from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 12C+ supports lateral joins, so you can do:

```
select t.id, v.col, v.val
from tbl t cross join lateral
     (select t.col, t.val from dual union all
      select t.col_1, t.val from dual
     ) v;
```

Comment: HA! You like lateral joins. :)

Comment: thanks Gordon for the answer. but is it possible to write this query via unpivot or regular expression? i want to avoid hitting same table multiple times.

Comment: @Ganesh . . . A lateral join does not "hit the same table multiple times".

Comment: Great, I will go through this lateral join concept. thanks for the info. (Y)

Answer (score 1):

You can pivot and unpivot multiple columns with the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` operators, you just need to know the correct syntax. In your case you want to `UNPIVOT`. You are losing some information in the way you show the desired output, and perhaps that's OK for your needs; in any case, below I include a column that shows the *order* of the pairs of columns. (A bit odd, showing `1` for `COL/VAL` and `2` for `COL_1/VAL_1`, but I assume those aren't your real column names anyway.) If you don't need the `ORD` column in the output, just drop it from the `SELECT` clause.

Note - `COLUMN` is an Oracle reserved word, it can't be a column name. I changed the column names to `C` and `V` in the output.

```
with
  input(id, col, col_1, val, val_1) as (
    select 1, 'ABC', 'DEF', 10, 20 from dual union all
    select 2, 'GHI', 'JKL', 30, 40 from dual
  )
select  id, ord, c, v
from    input
unpivot ( (c, v) for ord in ((col, val) as 1, (col_1, val_1) as 2))
;

        ID        ORD C            V
---------- ---------- --- ----------
         1          1 ABC         10
         1          2 DEF         20
         2          1 GHI         30
         2          2 JKL         40
```

Comment: superb,I  will try this .(Y)